# Inexpensive flash with full ETTL support

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, flash, ttl

I've been planning to get the [Canon 430EX](http://www.adorama.com/CA430EX2U.html?utm_source=gbase&utm_medium=Shopping%20Site&utm_campaign=Other&utm_term=Other), but I'd love to save a little cash, so I started looking at other 3rd party flashes. I've found a few that claim to have ETTL II support, but being so much cheaper, it makes me wonder about the quality.

That being said, does anyone know of a good, inexpensive flash with ETTL II support?

These are 2 of the ones I found:

- [Vivitar DF283 Digital TTL](http://www.adorama.com/VVDF283CAN.html)
- [Bower ETTL / ETTL II Zoom Flash](http://www.adorama.com/FASFD35C.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what ETTL-II is.

ETTL-II is a software improvement on using information with ETTL flashes and EF/EF-S lenses. It's implemented in **camera bodies**, not the flash-gun. So any flash that is ETTL compatible is automatically ETTL-II compatible when used with a Canon body that has ETTL-II.

As for a list of all bodies that have the improved ETTL-II, basically any Canon dSLR since 2004 has ETTL-II.

Regarding your question--inexpensive flash, I would go for the bigger Sigma [Fredrik Mörk](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/998/inexpensive-flash-with-full-ettl-support/999#999) posted over the 430ex (IIRC they're nearly the same price, but the sigma can act as a master, and has a higher guide number, and is more feature rich).

Answer (score 3):

The [Sigma EF-530 DG Super](http://www.adorama.com/SG530EOS.html) supports E-TTL II, and is supposed to be very good (a friend of mine had a couple before and was very happy about them).